# In Xcode Interface Builder - why are the options in the Editor--->Arrange menu (containing Send to Front, Send to Back) often disabled?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

What I'm trying to do is simple: bring a label in front of an image within a subview.

But all of the options for arranging are disabled/un-selectable when my label is selected. I find this happens often.

What could be the reason that I'm almost never allowed to change the z-axis of my objects in the Arrange menu? Is it a better practice to avoid this feature and set the order of views programmatically?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It happens sometimes. In that situation, click the view or image you want to send back then you will see little square box at the edges of image from which you can re size your image, Just click on it once and then go to **Editor**  > **Arrange** > Choose option according your need.

Comment: THIS is the correct answer for the original question.

Answer (score 37):

It can depend on how you have selected the label (similar to how the label can only be moved with the keyboard when selected in some ways).

A simple alternative is to look at the list of view in the pane on the left and to drag the views up and down to change the order.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. I'm fairly sure it was how I was clicking it - I ended up removing and adding to the subview a few times before the options appeared again. I also didn't realize that the left panel (list of views) is in reverse order of z-axis! Top is bottom!

Comment: I just found another way to fix this issue! Click the edge of the view as if to resize it for a moment, and then let go. Go to Editor/Arrange and the options will be selectable!